# Inject all keys and Values from property file as Map in Spring

Tags: java, spring

Can someone provide some idea to inject all dynamic keys and values from property file and pass it as `Map` to `DBConstants` class using Setter Injection with Collection.

Keys are not known in advance and can vary.

```
// Example Property File that stores all db related details
// db.properties

db.username.admin=root
db.password.admin=password12
db.username.user=admin
db.password.user=password13
```

`DBConstants` contains map dbConstants for which all keys and values need to be injected.

Please provide bean definition to inject all keys and values to Map dbConstants.

```
public class DBConstants {

    private Map<String,String> dbConstants;

    public Map<String, String> getDbConstants() {
        return dbConstants;
    }

    public void setDbConstants(Map<String, String> dbConstants) {
        this.dbConstants = dbConstants;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using Spring Boot or just regular Spring Framework?

Comment: Just spring framework.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create PropertiesFactoryBean with your properties file and then inject it with @Resource annotation where you want to use it as a map.

```
@Bean(name = "myProperties")
public static PropertiesFactoryBean mapper() {
    PropertiesFactoryBean bean = new PropertiesFactoryBean();
    bean.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("prop_file_name.properties"));
    return bean;
}
```

Usage:

```
@Resource(name = "myProperties")
private Map<String, String> myProperties;
```

Comment: @Alex_Java: Instead of `Map<String, String>` you can use `Properties`, both in the example above and in general.

Comment: I wasn't able to define the resource as a `Map<String, String>` and had to use `Properties` as suggested above.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `@Value`.

Properties file:

```
dbConstants={key1:'value1',key2:'value2'}
```

Java code:

```
@Value("#{${dbConstants}}")
private Map<String,String> dbConstants;
```

Comment: It does not work for me. Spring 'treats' this property as a String and cannot cast to Map.

Comment: What version of spring are you using? Have you tried out a newer version?

Comment: what new version do you mean? From what version spring supports it?

Comment: I got the issue... which got resolved by using like this.. https://stackoverflow.com/a/47451205/3450440

Answer (score 0):

you have to give spaces its like

```
hash.key = {indoor: 'reading', outdoor: 'fishing'}
```

Read map like below as i mentioned.

```
@Value("#{${hash.key}}")
private Map<String, String> hobbies;
```